# Sprites and light

Tags: babylonjs

Is there a way to have a `BABYLON.Sprite` affected by lights just the way meshes are?

The Sprite API has access to the RGB values, so indirectly it can be done, but I'm not sure there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is valid for an answer, but it worked for me.

```
const size = 10;

// sprites is an array of the sprites on my scene
sprites.forEach((sprite) => {
  const ratio = Vector3.Distance(sprite.position, light.position) / (size * 10);
  const val = light.intensity - ratio;
  sprite.color.set(val, val, val, 1);
});
```

Since the sprite affected by light is not supported by default, I think this workaround should do the trick(as a matter of fact, it does on my game).

Answer (score 0):

Hello if you want to get access to standard shades, the best way is then to use meshes with mesh.billboardMode = BABYLON.MESH.BILLBOARD_ALL

(http://doc.babylonjs.com/classes/2.3/AbstractMesh#billboardmode-number)

Comment: But this means replacing the Sprite with a Mesh?

Comment: Correct: a simple plane will suffice

Comment: Can animations and "always facing camera" be achieved with a plane?